# SQLite ORDER BY month number in a 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table with a column named `call_date` in the `DATETIME` format.

In this column I have the following date in this format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

**What I want is to select the rows ordered by the month number in the column's value String.**

**Is there such SQLite function that does that??**

I already tried `strftime('%m', call_date)` but ditn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: GO through the link provided in my answer. You will find related to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from myTable order by CAST(strftime('%m', call_date) AS INTEGER);
```

Comment: Can you help this is not working for me my code is below: "SELECT * FROM USER_DATA where strftime('%m', created_date) ='04'"; "created_date"->field name . In database my date format is "MM-dd-yyyy"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the month number and then order by that:

```
select ...
from your_table
order by strftime('%m', call_date)
```

Comment: It just doesnt order by the month number. =/

Comment: @rogcg: You can put multiple things in the ORDER BY, `order by strftime('%m', call_date), something_else desc, another_thing`

Comment: I want to order by the month number. So the months retrieved will be in perfect order. Is there a way to do that in a string with the format yyyy-mm-dd??

Comment: @rogcg: You can use the `strftime` SQLite SQL function to extract the month number from your `call_date`. If your `call_date` is `'2011-11-01`` then `strftime('%m', call_date)` will be `11`.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would try to avoid to order a result set by a calculated expression due to possible performance penalty. I would use an alternative approach: for example I would add MONTH column into the table and define a [TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) which will set the new column value. Then in queries you can order by a new column.