# Get age from date of birthday - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of people who I have to sort by their date of birth, only by the month, regardless of the year. From January to December. How can I do it in ruby ​​on rails?

In the same way, I need to be able to see the age in years on the edit screen of each person, instead of showing DD / MM / YY.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres....

You can use the [extract method](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-extract/) to create a sortable field:

```
@people = Person.select('extract("MONTH" from dob) as birth_month').order(birth_month: :asc)
```

where 'Person' is the presumed table name and 'dob' is the presumed column.

This is untested you might need to cast ::date or something in there. Check out the [extract method](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-extract/) though.

Comment: I am using sqlite, is it more complicated in this database?

Comment: thats actually answered in a different stack question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976205/sqlite-order-by-month-number-in-a-yyyy-mm-dd-format

Answer (score -1):

```
    dob = "01-01-2020"
    def age(dob)
      (Time.now.to_s(:number).to_i - dob.to_time.to_s(:number).to_i)/10e9.to_i
    end
```

Comment: And if I want to order only by month, using your date of birth regardless of the year.
What I mean is that it is grouped by month, January 2020, January 2021, February 2020, etc.
Thanks since now